# Where can I find a list of OpenID Provider URLs?

Tags: authentication, openid, dotnetopenauth

I've implemented OpenID on my website but I'm having a hard time finding a list of OpenID Provider URLs.  I thought this would be easy to find but I've scoured the web and only found a handful, mostly by accident.

Is there a resource that lists available Providers and their authentication URLs?

*EDIT: Here are the ones I've found so far.  I haven't tried all of them so let me know if any of them are wrong.*

> **StackExchange**     https://openid.stackexchange.com
>
> <s>**Google**         https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id - deprecated May 2014 - shutting down Apr 2015</s>
>
> **Yahoo**         https://me.yahoo.com
>
> **Flickr**        http://www.flickr.com/username
>
> **AOL**       http://openid.aol.com/username
>
> **Blogspot**  https://www.blogspot.com/
>
> **LiveJournal**   http://username.livejournal.com/
>
> **Wordpress**     https://username.wordpress.com/
>
> <s>**VerisignLabs**   https://pip.verisignlabs.com/ - closing down September 2016</s>
>
> <s>**MyOpenID**   https://www.myopenid.com/ - slated to be shut down Feb 2014</s>
>
> **MyVidoop**  https://myvidoop.com/
>
> **Technorati**    https://technorati.com/people/technorati/username/
>
> **PayPal** https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides/standard-openid-integration-paypal-access

Comment: Put in the ones you have found so far and *this* can be the list

Comment: Silly me...if you're not part of the solution :-)

Comment: Flickr works with you? does not work with Hybrid_auth(lightopenid) so far http://oyanix.com/opensource/hybridauth/widget_authentication/mywebsite/index.php

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you're missing one of the points of OpenID - it's a decentralized system that doesn't have a "master list" - anyone can setup their own OpenID server.  If software is built such that it follows the OpenID specifications, it won't need to know the URL of the server ahead of time.

Comment: Exactly. Focus, maybe what would be better is asking for a list of popular OpenID providers.

Comment: Well, on my site I want to have a login prompt similar to what SO uses in that X number of providers are already available to you to use so you don't have to remember https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id if you want to use google.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ya... Stack Overflow has chosen several Providers to list, and the rest never show up in Stack Overflow's login screen.  If that's what you're trying to emulate, you don't need a comprehensive list list Providers... just the ones you want to list.

Comment: The problem with this decentralized implementation is that the user has to know his OpenId -Link. Stackoverflow uses a link- free approach and google [suggests](https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin/emailonlylogin) the same.  In this context, it makes a lot of sense to have a list of standard openId links.

Comment: and that's not all, having a list of as many OpenID providers as possible allows for more extensive testing on thw whole subject.

Answer (score 34):

I would propose to use the http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/ library.
It has the most used urls + graphics for each site.

It is what stackoverflow uses.

Comment: I like this answer more than the accepted one :)  While I know the point and idea behind OpenID, the average Joe isn't going to know what the Google/Yahoo/etc. endpoints are, so such a list or tool that is provided in this answer is highly beneficial to a developer.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't forget that OpenID Delegation means that I should be able to use any host I own and control to delegate for my OpenID at another provider. That means that beyond just having any number of id providers, from corporate and community driven, to personal or family based, you further have the issue of having delegation allow for anyone's domain or sub-domain constitute an id. E.G. my-popular-blog.com maybe delegated to popularblogger.myopenid.com.

Answer (score 2):

Such a list cannot be  complete. The whole point of OpenID is that identity management is NOT linked to a single or a small number of providers.
So I can give you an other identity provider: openid.basjes.nl.
This provider handles the OpenID of exactly 1 user (perhaps 2 if my wife wants one too).

The effect I do see lately is that sites want users to be able to login with a lower threshold. Many of those users already have an account that is (technically) exposed using OpenID, but these users are not aware of this fact  nor do they understand what OpenID is.

So what happens is that sites (like SO) add a few 'convenience' buttons that translate (Javascript?) the site specific userid to the corresponding OpenID. But only for the 'top 5' most popular sites. For the rest they have a normal OpenID.

Just my 2ct.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called **Identity URL**.

Add these to the list:

- MySpace: www.myspace.com/username
- Blogger: blogname.blogspot.com
- Hyves: hyves.net
- Orange: orange.fr
- Mixi: mixi.com

(I'm new here so I cannot post more than 2 URLs. You need to add http://)

I need Identity URLs for:

- Facebook
- Twitter
- LinkedIn
- Windows Live ID

Anyone ?

Edit:

I've got this list also

www.digitalenginesoftware.com/blog/archives/24-OpenID-Provider-URL-Formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a small list of URLs [<s>here</s>](http://spreadopenid.org/provider-comparison/) ([archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20091230182837/http://spreadopenid.org/provider-comparison)).