# List of openid urls

Tags: php, openid, openid-selector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a list of OpenID Provider URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116743/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-openid-provider-urls)

I am creating an openid authentication code for my website. I need to show a list of URL's (google, yahoo, etc) that the users can select. I can't find all the open id URL's of these other websites. Is there a list somewhere?

I know that google is https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id. Is there a list showing major openid providers and their URLs?

Answer (score 6):

Yahoo! and Google are the only OpenID-Providers which don't want the username to be in the URL (Yahoo! has me.yahoo.com).

A list of different OpenID-Providers and their URLs is on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=OpenID&oldid=462988371#OpenID_Providers)

(and on [SpreadOpenID.org](http://spreadopenid.org/provider-comparison/) was a list)

Comment: Hi Azmisov, I've updated the Wikipedia-Link to a permalink.

Comment: I cant find my Yahoo OpenID URL anymore. http://openid.yahoo.com show a friendly 404. So does  me.yahoo.com.  Any clue what has happened to it? I don't find any resource of the WEB that gives any hint