# List of Direct OpenID Providers that utilize unbound discoverable URLs?

Tags: openid, openid-provider, google-openid, openid-selector

Anyone has a list of Direct OpenID Providers that utilize *unbound discoverable URLs*?

So far, I have only found these:
myopenid, 
yahoo, 
Hyves,
myspace, 
myid.net,
google,
yahoo japan,
AOL,
Verisign.

Comment: What do you mean by "unbound discoverable URL"? Also, you should never assume that any given list of providers is complete. OpenID is a fully decentralized system, and it's just impossible to list every existing provider.

Comment: "unbound discoverable URLs" have no username associated with it. For e.g. yahoo.com vs. userid.wordpress.com .

i understand that a comprehensive list is not possible, i am just looking for a list of the "popular" ones. I need to use these in a PoC app.

Thanks,
Saqib

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have searched some, but I didn't test if they are correct:

- **Google** https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
- **Yahoo!** https://me.yahoo.com
- **Blogspot** https://www.blogspot.com/
- **VeriSign** https://pip.verisignlabs.com/
- **MyOpenID** https://www.myopenid.com/
- **MyVidoop** https://myvidoop.com/
- **AOL** https://www.aol.com/
- **Livejournal** http://www.livejournal.com/openid/server.bml
- **Chi.mp** http://chi.mp/

A list of different OpenID-Providers and their URLs is on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#OpenID_Providers) and on [SpreadOpenID.org](http://spreadopenid.org/provider-comparison/). Another site with a list is [here](http://mysqltalk.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/popular-openid-endpoints/). As OpenID is a decentralised service, nobody can give you a definite list.

Related questions:

- [Where can I find a list of OpenID Provider URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116743/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-openid-provider-urls)
- [List of openid urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791465/list-of-openid-urls)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand the OpenID is a decentralized service, but we should be able to create a wiki page somewhere to maintain a list.