# OpenID integration

Tags: php, openid

How can I integrate OpenID into my website so people can login with their Google, Twitter, or Facebook credentials?

Comment: Twitter and Facebook are no OpenID providers AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you bother to look at the OpenID site?

- [Here's a list of libraries, there's a ton of options for PHP.](http://openid.net/developers/libraries)
- [Here's a list of plugins for popular content management scripts.](http://wiki.openid.net/Website_Software)
- [Janrain User Management Platform (JUMP)](http://www.janrain.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a mixture of technologies to achieve that. OpenID is technology that will allow your users to login with Google (and Yahoo and [many other providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116743/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-openid-provider-urls)), Twitter and Facebook both are using OAuth protocol but it's easier to grab a API specific for given vendor.

I've implemented a ready made solution ([working demo](http://openid.doppnet.com/)) that makes use of [LightOpendID](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid) (to allow login with Google/Yahoo account), [Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) and [Twitter](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) APIs, you can [grab it on github](https://github.com/tnajdek/single-sign-on-implementation).